# What is the best backport of Android switch widget for 2.2?

Tags: android

Im looking for a stable backport of android switch widget for 2.2. Please recommend open source library that you are using.

Comment: @dhara shah updated link:https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

or

https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/tree/master/android-switch-demo

Are a couple of easy options.

I also found it relatively simple to subclass SeekBar to get the effect desired (very similar to the iOS switch).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [this](https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary) and [this](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). The second one I think is much more than you expect, and remember to install Maven if you choose it.

Comment: I found that SwitchCompatLibrary did not handle the preference subclass or the different kinds of thumbs that android-switch-backport does.