# Is it possible to use Switch widget in Android honeycomb 3.x?

Tags: android, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-switch

It always give me the following exception in runtime:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file exception line #291: Error inflating class android.widget.Switch

However, I added the latest Android Support Library to my project but it did not contain the Switch widget feature. I think Google did not add it yet to the Support Library.

Comment: So what did you end up with? Was any of the answers of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use switch < 4.0

But however these are custom projects of switch you can use...

[Pre Android Switch](https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/tree/master/android-switch-demo) and [android-switch-backport](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport)

Answer (score 1):

Switch widget is unavailable on Android prior to API 14, it's also not included in support library. Though there are some backports which you can find here: [What is the best backport of Android switch widget for 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008384/what-is-the-best-backport-of-android-switch-widget-for-2-2)